# VS Code EXPLORER view renames to FOLDERS in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code on Windows, when I open a folder, the EXPLORER view gets renamed to the FOLDERS view. But this does not happen in Linux. Why? (I have found nothing online about this, in searches or in VS Code docs. I can't even find an instance of it happening in a YouTube tutorial on VS Code.)

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem . . .

[image: Before opening a folder]

[image: After opening a folder]

Comment: @starball Thank you! While that wasn't exactly my question, the "nuclear option" suggested in the answer ("View: Reset View Locations") did cause my "Explorer" view to stop being replaced by the "Folders" view. So this solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Running the command "View: Reset View Locations" stopped my EXPLORER view from always being replaced by the FOLDERS view when opening a folder. Thank you to @starball for pointing me in the right direction.